# How to disable auto load of applications on restart/turn on over OS X Catalina?

Tags: macos, mac, catalina

Every time when I turn on my mac it immediately opens previous applications...

For example - Safari and Video editor were opened before to turn off my laptop I closed all applications and then shut down the laptop. Next time when I turn my mac on it immediately opens again last closed applications (Safari and Video editor for example).

I found this answer on SO

https://superuser.com/questions/327460/how-to-disable-auto-load-of-applications-on-restart-over-os-x-lion

it did not help

Also, I checked auto-loading applications

[image]

There are not any applications listed as auto-loading.

So, question is - how to disable these recent auto-loadings?

Comment: I can't comment on Catalina specifically, but I've noticed in the past that the auto-opening seems to depend on a timer of sorts. If you Quit an app & immediately restart, the app will reopen. If you give it a couple of minutes before restarting, it won't. I don't restart often enough to have really measured this or done any actual experimentation on it; it's just a 'hunch'.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, it sounds like you are right... But how to disable this option?

Comment: To confirm, you have unchecked the "reopen windows" box mentioned in the SuperUser post?

Comment: @drivec of course

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a permanent solution, but from what you are describing it only happens when you recently close an app and then restart your computer. [Here is a screenshot from a support article on the Apple Support website](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-items-automatically-when-you-log-in-mh15189/mac) [image: Apple Support Fix] Along with this solution instead of closing the application, make sure that it is totally closed (the little white dot below the application is gone).

---

For example: 

Application still open: [image: Open Application Logo] 

Application totally closed: [image: Closed Application Logo]

Let me know if any of this helps!